# import a set of text file to mysql using mysql or python code

Tags: python, mysql

I have a folder which contains a set of file .txt with the same structure.

The folder directory is E:\DataExport

Which contain 1000 .txt file: text1.txt, text2.txt,....
Each txt file contain price data of one. The data is updated on a daily. An example of one .txt file is as below

```
Ticker,Date/Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
AAA,7/15/2010,19.581,20.347,18.429,18.698,174100
AAA,7/16/2010,19.002,19.002,17.855,17.855,109200
AAA,7/19/2010,19.002,19.002,17.777,17.777,104900
....
```

My question is, I want to:

1. Load all the file into mysql data base through a line of code, I can do it one by one in MySql command line but do not know how to import all at once, into one table in MySql (I have already create the table)
2. Everyday, when I get new data, how could I only update the new data to the table in MySql

I would like to get solution using either Python or MySql. I have tried to google and apply some solution but cannot success, the data do not load into mySQL

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use python package `pandas`.

   Read data with [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) into `DataFrame` and use [`to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method with proper `con` and `schema`.
2. You will have to keep track of what is imported. You could for example keep it in file or database that last imported 54th line on 1032th file. And perform an update that reads the rest and imports that.